# Android Calendar View - How to customize Calendar View to make it like Google Calendar App one?

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

In recent Google Calendar App , it has a calendar which can be pulled down to show, and display in the style like this:

[image]

I wanted to build a Calendar like this to the App, but when I put the android API `CalendarView` to the app, its style is very different:

[image]

So, the problem is how could I style/customize the CalendarView to like the one in Google Calendar App?

Also, for Google Calendar App's calendar, when there is an event on a particulate, there will be "small dots" under the date text (Like the 19th and 21th of Augest in the above Google Calendar's image). How to achieve something like this, when I am having a list of dates (NOT events of android calendar, just a list of dates) and wanted to mark a dot on these dates on the Calendar, like what the Google Calendar App did?

Answer (score 1):

I have found one project which create dropdown view like `Google calendar` app

Use this : [Sample Project](https://github.com/jignesh13/googlecalendar)

Which is use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside it put custom calenderView which set dots on event date also it copy of google calendar app

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/ann"
        app:expanded="false"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior=".MyAppBarBehavior"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap|enterAlways"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

            <!--large view -->
            <com.example.GoogleCalendar.GooglecalenderView
                android:id="@+id/calander"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
              >


            </com.example.GoogleCalendar.GooglecalenderView>

            <!--top toolbar-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:title="fkdl"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/backsupport"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/monthname"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/googlesans_regular"
                        android:text="June"
                        android:textColor="#464646"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arrowImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/monthname"
                        android:translationX="-5dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />
                                 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.example.GoogleCalendar.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nestedView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to build a Calendar like this to the App

You can use [This Library](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview) to achieve what you want.

> In recent Google Calendar App , it has a calendar which can be pulled down to show

You can hide/show your calendar view using animations.

> there will be "small dots" under the date text

I've achieved this using this library but you need to study it a bit and modify it.This is using a canvas to build the calendar view and You can add circles on your dates using the x,y coordinates of these dates.Just pass the dates to this lib and use `drawCircle()` method for canvas.

Comment: Could you please provide link to the source code for how you modified the library and made a custom calendar with events as asked by the OP here ? I am also aiming for a similar custom calendar implementation, but I see the library having multiple months in one view, and no event decoration functionality built-in.

Comment: @KunalChawla it was a long time back and it was for a company project. So i don't have the code now and in the meantime it is very much possible that the library might have changed internally. But it was not that hard..just try to go through classes and try to play with it.

Comment: Does anyone know any open source library that extend Android's `CalendarView` which allows easy customization for Date's cell drawable? I see many suggested libraries but they implement their own Calendar View which aren't extending from Android's `CalendarView`.